# Java Preserve JSON message on JsonMappingException

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I am trying to log the JSON message that failed the parsing using the com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue method:

```
jsonRequest = mapper.readValue(reader, Request.class);
```

On invoking the method above sometimes I get a JsonMappingException.  On catching the JsonMappingException I cannot find the JSON message that failed.

I would need to log the JSON message. Has anyone any idea on how to retrieve the original JSON message?

Thanks

Comment: put your exception log as well

Answer (score 0):

If the [JsonMappingException](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonMappingException.html) is from fasterxml, it has additional methods for path reference that cause problems with Serialization or deserialization.

> Checked exception used to signal fatal problems with mapping of content.
>
> One additional feature is the ability to denote relevant path of references (during serialization/deserialization) to help in troubleshooting.

As suggested, `exception.printStackTrace()` should give you complete trace of the problem.

[This](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-exception) suggests various exceptions and their problem resolutions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, I do not get the full JSON message.